# Laravel - Merge "phone" and "telephone" into the same field

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel

I am trying to merge different column names like "phone" and "telephone" into one in Laravel.

I also want to do it for "first_name" and "firstname", etc

In my table I have rows with phone and others with telephone.
Here is my line to get the data :

```
$landing_datas =  \App\LandingData::whereIn('landing_id', $landinds_ids)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
```

How could I achieve what I want to do please ?

Comment: its better if you can restructure your data, take a backup of your database then update phone column with telephone values where phone is null, same for first_name and when all looks okay then drop telephone and firstname column from your database but first perform these steps on backup instance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge them into one column in your database do it like described by M Khalid Junaid.

You can also [define an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to join both numbers

```php
public function getPhoneNumberAttribute(): string
{
    return "{$this->phone}, {$this->telephone}";
}
```

and then you can access it via `$model->phone_number`.

This, of course, is only applicable if you want to display them properly in Laravel and does not solve the issue with having them in multiple columns.